# AngularJS passing data to Javascript variables and opposite

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am looking for a solution on passing data from a specific input text field to AngularJS. it may be a Javascript variable too. If the variable is changed from inside a javascript code it is not updating on AngularJS side. If i take the same variable and in the text field add at least one character or modify something i see variable updating and everything working as it should.

I tried something with angular.element(document.getElementById('ControllerElementID')).scope().funct(); but still no luck. When i update at least one field from the keyboard, all text fields that are related to "**ng-model="sig.sigBase6422"**" are updating properly as it should. If i call this updates through a JavaScript function i see updates only on specific text field and **no updates** at all on **ng-model** happening. How to make it updating as simple as possible? Below i will post a small example. I was able to store data from variable to a external file and in AngularJS read it from file and use it. this is way too long, complicated and ridiculous. I am sure there should be a better way.

Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addtext1() {document.getElementById("myID1").value = "1111111111111111";}
function addtext2() {document.getElementById("myID2").value = "2222222222222222";}
</script>

<div>
    <form action="#" name="FORM1">
    <TEXTAREA NAME="sigData" ng-model="sig.sigBase6422" ROWS="10" COLS="20">String: </TEXTAREA>
    </form><br>
    <input type="text" name="myID1" id="myID1" ng-model="sig.sigBase6422" ><br>
    <input type="text" name="myID2" id="myID2" ng-model="sig.sigBase6422" ><br>
    <p>Value {{sig.sigBase6422}}!</p>
</div>

<!-- test field -->
<a href="javascript:addtext1()">Add text 1</a>
<a href="javascript:addtext2()">Add text 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed if you want to use AngularJS for what it was created, you have to rewrite your code completely using `directive` or `controller`. You variables and functions accessible from the view should be attached to the `$scope` too.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    
    $scope.addtext1 = function () {
        $scope.sig.sigBase6422 += "1111111111111111";
    };
    $scope.addtext2 = function () {
        $scope.sig.sigBase6422 += "2222222222222222";
    };

    $scope.sig = {
        sigBase6422: ""
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form action="#" name="FORM1">
        <TEXTAREA ng-model="sig.sigBase6422" ROWS="10" COLS="20">String: </TEXTAREA>
    </form><br/>
    <input type="text" name="myID1" id="myID1" ng-model="sig.sigBase6422" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="myID2" id="myID2" ng-model="sig.sigBase6422" /><br/>
    <p>Value {{sig.sigBase6422}}!</p>

    <!-- test field -->
    <button ng-click="addtext1()">Add text 1</button>
    <button ng-click="addtext2()">Add text 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I simulated the code snippet. it is exactly what i was looking for :) I have directives, controllers, and services inside the angular scripts. i will move the angular portion on controller side and script to html side.  The only disadvantage is that i have to rewrite the entire native javascript to angular. Let me try it. Thanks for help!

Comment: You're welcome. Do not forget to accept the answer :-)

Comment: I am still having a issue here. i need this to have both native and angular scripts separate. something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/8FSW7yR8eYOdIXnUUbse?p=preview in this example 2 variables are picked by Angular from an external javascript. The issue is that i have an external application running on this javascript and is giving me dynamic variables always. And Angular is supposed to capture them and display properly in forms.

Comment: Angular controller's scope is the dom element where you attach it. It can be inherited by children scopes. But it cannot move outside of your `<div ng-controller=...`

Comment: I was reading a lot this days and found a pretty easy solution.     `//dynamicvariable comincg from native javascript`

`var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng model="sig.sigBase6422"]')).scope();`
`scope.$apply(function() {`
`scope.sig.sigBase6422 = dynamicvariable`
`});`

Comment: Yeah that's easy, quick and dirty. Think it twice why you moved to Angular in the first place. If you want a smooth move to full Angular and look for a temporary solution, that's ok. Otherwise you may end up with lots of boilerplate code if you have to maintain 2 systems and their interactions. I'm happy you've got something, and sorry I spent time on the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood how angular works. What you're trying to do is not how angular works. What you're trying to do with native JavaScript can be done with angular. Angular can update dom and Dom updates angular as it's responsible for causing updates.... anyway without getting any deeper. You need to read more on how angular works and try sticl within the bounds of angular instead of mixing.

That being said :
Tigger change on the Dom element after you have updated its value. Or better yet get access to scope variable on the Dom and call a function in angular with the value you're and set they value from inside of a angular.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code while updating the value.

pick the controller first using

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID')).scope();
scope.<variablename> = <your operation>;
```

then

```
scope.$apply();
```

the remaining thing will be taken care by Angular.

Comment: i am testing using this ideea and while i am triyng to read from the element ID and i am receiving "object OBJECT" how to take the ID value from the object?

Comment: thanks var scope and scope apply worked for me. thank you for suggestion!